# My CodeMirror textarea doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, codemirror

I wrote some HTML code to use CodeMirror to highlight code in my textarea. I wanna do this for javascript, but I don't understand why there are no text highlights in my textarea.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="js/codemirror.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="codemirror-4.7/lib/codemirror.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/docs.css">
  <script src="codemirror-4.7/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
  <title>TestHTML</title>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea id="code">
  </textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(document.getElementById("code"), {
  mode:"javascript",
  lineNumbers: true 
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code. So maybe you can find my mistake :)

Edit:

The error code is:

```
GET    file://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/sourcesanspro/v5/ODelI1aHBYDBqgeIAH2zlBM0YzuT7MdOe03otPbuUS0.woff net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: Is `mode="javascript"` a typo? Shouldn't be `mode:"javascript"`?

Comment: yes it is. but it has no influence, as I tested it again :/

Comment: `lineNumbers: true;` with the semicolon at the end is likely to be another syntax error.  Try opening your dev tools with F12 and see if any errors are reported in your console.

Comment: That error is unlikely to be preventing CodeMirror from working.  You've also left the unedited code with both syntax errors in place - can you edit it to be the exact code you're now testing with?

Comment: edited it. before testing it with dev tools, i fixed the mistakes.

Comment: Ok.  I think you need to relook at [the API](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api).  It seems that it will be trying to append itself to your `textarea`.  You either need to put a placeholder element in place, or use the [`fromTextArea`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#fromTextArea) method

Answer (score 3):

The way you're invoking the CodeMirror constructor tells it to append itself to a textarea -- which is a kind of element that can't have children. You probably want to call `CodeMirror.fromTextArea` instead of plain `CodeMirror`.